# Converting ArrayList to Map

Tags: java, list, arraylist, dictionary

I have arrayList

```
ArrayList<Product> productList  = new ArrayList<Product>();
 productList  = getProducts();  //Fetch the result from db
```

This list is stored in an ArrayList. The problem is that when I print its data, I obtain :

```
A, Arizona, 1980
B, Arizona, 1970
C, NewYork, 1980
D, NewYork, 1970
E, California, 1960
```

I want to convert to ArrayList to Map based on area:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, List<Product>>>//Integer here is year and String here is manufacturingArea
```

The Product bean has the following structure :

```
class Product{
    private String name;
    private String manufacturingArea;
    private int year;
    /* Getters and setters*/
    /* toString method */
}
```

I'd like to convert to map like this :

```
{1980= [Arizona,A], [NewYork,C]},
{1970= [NewYork,B],[NewYork,D]},
{1960= [California,E]}
```

how can I group the data by converting arraylist to map?

Comment: you have to map it maually

Comment: One loop over the array to create the map should do the trick. And another loop to print the map. What have you tried?

Comment: Your map declaration and your data do not match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
Map<String, List<Product>> newMap = new HashMap<String, List<Product>>();

for (Product product: productList) {
   if (!newMap.containsKey(product.name)) 
        newMap.put(product.name, new ArrayList<Product>())
   newMap.get(product.name).add(product)
}
```

Per the update to the question, note that `year` is private, but I am assuming it is readable in the context. The following code is untested, but should get you pretty close.

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, List<Product>>> newMap = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, List<<Product>>>();
for (Product product: productList) {
   if (!newMap.containsKey(product.year)) // Java should do auto-boxing here 
        newMap.put(product.year, new HashMap<String, Product>());
   if (!newMap.get(product.year).containsKey(product.manufacturingArea);
        newMap.get(product.year).put(product.manufacturingArea, new ArrayList<Product>());

   newMap.get(product.year).get(product.manufacturingArea).add(product));
}
```

Comment: I've a feeling that the OP wants to know about how to print it in the format he/she wants rather than how to convert it to a Map. But, ofcourse, I may be wrong too!

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ, He removed the accept after I edited, so I guess he didn't want it :P

Comment: @merlin2011: I tried above code. `HashMap` replaces the previous value associated with the given key in the map (conceptually like an array indexing operation for primitive types).

Comment: @Unknown, checking this.

Comment: @merlin2011 - Honestly, I'd prefer you keep both the parts of the answer. Extra information is never harmful you see :)

Comment: @Unknown, I do not have enough of your existing code to reproduce, but `containsKey` should be able to handle `String` primitive.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ, Will put it back in after I figure out why the above code is not working for him.

Comment: @Unknown, I have added untested code which should get you pretty close.

Comment: @merlin2011: Thanks Bro. Its working fine. Instead of `HashMap` I used `LinkedHashMap` to save data with duplicate keys.